# Protect everything but the value of a cell or range of cells in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to protect **everything but** the value of a cell or range of cells?

I want to protect all formatting, data validation, etc. but still allow other users to update the data in the cells.

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You could theoretically write a script update the formatting back to your style during the onEdit() trigger.

Something like - some pseudo code:

```
function onEdit(event){
    var ss = event.source.getActiveSheet();
    var range = event.source.getActiveRange();
    if(range.getBackgrounds()){ //or whatever you want to stay the same
        range.setBackgrounds(blue)//
    } 
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    return;
}
```

Edit: I don't know how you could protect your data validation though.